# Pass Values from JSON as Props to the child component

Tags: reactjs

I have a JSON file with some values, i can show that value to my component by mapping.

My json:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "Name": "Nandhini",
}]
```

Example:

```
import Namedata from "./data/namedata";

{
    Namedata.map((user) => {
        return (
            <Card>
                <Meta name={user.Name} />
            </Card>
        )
    })
}
```

**I want to pass these data as props to the child component. how to achieve this?**

Example Parent Component (the value i need to pass from):

```
import Namedata from "./data/namedata";

<div>
 <UserNameComponent Name={Namedata}/>
</div>
```

Example child component:

i know this is wrong, need solution to call that value here!!

```
 {
        this.props.Namedata.map((user) => {
            return (
                <Card>
                    <Meta name={user.Name} />
                </Card>
            )
        })
    }
```

Comment: Just use {Name} in the UserNameComponent b/c that's what you named the prop.

Comment: You are sending `Name` as a property to a child. So change to `this.props.Name.map(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have come closer. Everything seems right except for one thing. 
When you are accessing props that are received from Parent, you should refer to the name you pass as an attribute. In this case **Name**, not **Namedata**.

Hence this should work.

```
{
this.props.Name.map((user) => {
   return (
       <Card>
           <Meta name={user.Name} />
       </Card>
   )
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have passed your `Namedata` as `Name` in youe child component `UserNameComponent`. So try to access `Name` property from child and not `NameData`

```
 {
        this.props.Name.map((user) => {
            return (
                <Card>
                    <Meta name={user.Name} />
                </Card>
            )
        })
    }
```